# JAX-RS resource method signatures

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey 2.19 to implement a REST API.

I'd like to know how I find out from the Jersey user guide or other specification how I'm supposed to know what the signature of my JAX-RS resource should be.

E.g. for a resource that handles POST requests I've experimented with the following different signatures using examples I've found.

```
public Response myResource()
public Response myResource(String param)
```

Both of these are valid in that they compile and run and the method is called under the right conditions.

Can anyone tell me where it is specified what the signatures should be and what the parameters mean? It seems like a straightforward question but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Generally anything not annotated is considered part of the request entity body. You can only have one of these. The rest of the method parameters need to be annotated accordingly. If you would like to know what possible annotations there are for method parameters, and what they are for, that's a pretty broad topic and the answer is scattered all through [the documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying its a `POST` request , so it should recieve some data from the Request. So you should expect something in Parameter.
`public Response myResource(String param)`
But the `type` of parameter should depend upon actually `@Consumes` annotation like :-

`@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` : This expects a `JSON`input OR 
`@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` : This expects a `XML`input OR
`@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)` : This expects a `String` plain text input

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You annotate your Methods like described in the [official documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2011).
Also, do not forget to annotate the service-class with `@Path`

```
@Path("MyService")
public class MyService
{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/User")
    public List<User> getUser()
    {
        //Return all users
    }

    //Inserts new User in JSON Format
    @Get
    @Path("/User/UserId/{userid}")
    public User getUserById(@PathParam("userid") String userid)
    {
        //Find User with ID in Database and return it
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUserById(User user)
    {
        //add user to your Database or something
    }
}
```

If you now want to get all users in json format you have to call:
`http://ip-address/MyService/user`

Comment: There are examples in that linked document that have no parameters and a parameter that is a byte array. Furthermore, there isn't an example like the one you've listed.

Comment: I tried to extend my Answer and make an example with a service adding and returning users

Comment: You tell Jersey what your Methods consume and produce; and you tell Jersey the path to your service and the methods of your service

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I think you're missing the point. I have managed to find examples on various sites similar to the one you have provided. But my question asks where is the official place where these signatures are specified?

Comment: Well the official place IS the official documentation I already linked. https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an exact answer to your question, but gird your loins. Because if the Jersey docs are overly vague these are in the extreme opposite direction: written by someone showing off their PhD in abstract algebra it looks to me.

The answer to everything is in the JAX-RS spec, of which Jersey is an *implementation*. You can download it [here as PDF](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339) (after you sign away your soul)

The specific answer to how one of those methods is selected instead of the other, is too detailed for me to paste in here, but it's under section "**3.7.2 Request Matching**"

I won't even *try* to paste in the mathematical rules used to set up the list of potential methods to match a request, then select from among them. There's no chance of getting them formatted readably in SO.

For your more general questions, the section "**3.3 Resource Methods**" is much more accessible. Here are a few choice excerpts:

> 3.3 Resource Methods
>
> ...
> JAX-RS defines a set of
> request method designators for the common HTTP methods: @GET, @POST,
> @PUT, @DELETE, @HEAD and @OPTIONS.
> ...
>
> 3.3.1 Visibility:  Only public methods may be exposed as resource methods.
> ...
>
> 3.3.2 Parameters: Resource methods MUST have at most one entity parameter ...
>
> 3.3.3 Return Type: Resource methods MAY return void, Response, GenericEntity, or another Java type...

etc, etc.